# C# determine a Nullable property DateTime type when using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

I have a question on how to determine an object's Nullable property type.

`ObjectA` has a property `DateTime? CreateDate;`

When I iterate through its properties like the following code, how do I check if a property is a `Nullable DateTime` type?

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in ObjectA.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    //do the compare here
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
pi.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)
```

Comment: another question thou...
how do I do switch based on the type? do i have to use fullname instead? or should be using "If" statement instead?

what's the string FullName for a Nullable DateTime type?

thank you

Comment: I would strongly advise you to use `if`, and avoid `FullName`. If you want to see `FullName` for `DateTime?`, then just print out `typeof(DateTime?).FullName` - but it's going to be lengthy, will make your code less readable, be brittle (what if you occasionally delete a character somewhere?), and will result in slower comparisons (`Type` objects themselves are compared by reference - i.e. there's at most one `Type` object for any given, so if two references are equal, then this is the same type; and such comparison is fast)

Answer (score 4):

```
pi.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(DateTime?))
```