# How to test a DataGridView cell/column for Date OR Nullable Date?

Tags: .net, types

We have some code which takes any datagridview and does stuff with the rows and columns.

For some operations behaviour depends on the column data type.

We can test for System.String etc.

```
If grd.Columns(x).ValueType Is GetType(System.String) Then
...
Endif
```

or if you prefer:

```
if (grd.Columns(x).ValueType == typeof(System.String)) {
}
```

Date columns can be tested the same way.

But if we want to test, basically, is this column a **Date** **OR** **Nullable Date** how can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1180736/180430) helped. Seems GetType (or typeof) is just as happy with `DateTime?` as with `DateTime`.

So we can just ask

```
If ... Is GetType(DateTime) or ... Is GetType(DateTime?) Then
```

and off we go.

p.s. or indeed `GetType(Nullable(Of DateTime))`